# Rewarded videos in chartboost not working!?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, chartboost

So I added the didcomplete rewarded video function to my gamescene.swift and it doesn’t execute the code! It is written in swift! Please help!

Comment: Please share your code.
Most common issue is you are not setting the delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you didn't call the function?

Or you installed the virus program Steam?
Better activate your Ikarus!